# Can Only Scrape Portion of Table with Python and BS4

Tags: python, python-requests, wikipedia, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape the table with the draft order from [this wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2012_NFL_Draft)

I am having a problem where the only data that is being pulled is from the rows with a different background color (the ones with an '*' next to the round number).

My code is as follows:

```
wikiURL = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2012_NFL_Draft"

#create array to store player info in
teams_players = []

# request and parse wikiURL
r = requests.get(wikiURL)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")

#find table in wikipedia
playerData = soup.find('table', {"class": "wikitable sortable"})

for row in playerData.find_all('tr'):
    cols = row.find_all('td')

    if len(cols) == 9: 

        teams_players.append((cols[3].text.strip(), cols[4].text.strip()))

for team, player in teams_players:
    print('{:35} {}'.format(team, player))
```

Comment: if you'll look to source HTML, you'll see that it has slightly more dificullt structure than table->tr->td, so you should parse it more complexly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because of the `if len(cols) == 9:` condition. You need to:

- skip the first header row
- look for both `td` and `th` elements inside every `tr`
- skip rows with count less than 6

Fixed version:

```
for row in playerData.find_all('tr')[1:]:
    cols = row.find_all(['td', 'th'])
    if len(cols) < 6:
        continue
    teams_players.append((cols[5].text.strip(), cols[6].text.strip()))
```

Prints:

```
QB                                  Stanford
QB                                  Baylor
...
RB                                  Abilene Christian
QB                                  NIU
```

Comment: This works, but what was wrong with the '(if len(cols) == 9:)' condition? Isn't  the number of columns in each row constant?

Comment: @Michael nope, see both `th` and `td` elements were used to represent cells in a row.